# C# asynchronous tasks with Task.WhenAll() not working

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await

I am trying to execute multiple tasks asynchronously. And then wait for all before proceeding.
But somehow my all tasks are not completing. Review my sample code.

```
//List from database
List<Promotion> promotions = _dbContext.promotions.ToList();

var promotionTasks = new List<Task>();
List<Promotion> outputPromotions = new List<Promotion>();
foreach (var promotion in promotions)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var promotionStatus = GetPromotionStatus(promotion).Result;
        var newPromotion = new Promotion
        {
            Id = promotion.Id,
            Name = promotion.Name,
            Code = promotion.Code,
            StatusId = promotionStatus
        };

        outputPromotions.Add(newPromotion);
    });
    promotionTasks.Add(task);
}

//await Task.WhenAll(promotionTasks);
Task.WaitAll(promotionTasks.ToArray());

//Output list
return outputPromotions;
```

For e.g
I am getting 50 values in `promotions` (which is original list and its from database). and then after the completion of all tasks i am not getting the all 50 values in outputPromotions consistantly.
`outputPromotions` it gives me count like 49,48,50,46 not all 50 every time.
I have tried await `Task.WhenAll(promotionTasks);` and `Task.WaitAll(promotionTasks.ToArray());` both but same result.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `List<T>` isn't safe for multi-threaded access.

Comment: Using `Task.Run` inside a loop only to *block* by calling `.Result` is self-defeating

Comment: What does `GetPromotionStatus` do? It matters. Task.Run probably isn't needed and the code could be converted to a simple LINQ query and a Task.WhenAll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<>` isn't thread-safe. That `Task.Run` doesn't seem to be doing anything useful either - it just blocks waiting for another asynchronous method to respond.

The mixing of async-await and blocking calls like `.Result` can also result in potential deadlocks

Make the code async all the way

#### Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

The code could be replaced with :

```
var tasks = promotions.Select(async promotion=>
               {
                   var status=await GetPromotionStatus(promotion);
                   return new Promotion                    
                   {
                       Id = promotion.Id,
                       Name = promotion.Name,
                       Code = promotion.Code,
                       StatusId = status
                   }
               });
Promotion[] newPromotions = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If you want to convert that array to a list, you can just use `.ToList()` on it, or the [List(IEnumerable) constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__), eg :

```
var newList = newPromotions.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer will try this.

Comment: You commented that List are not, obviously, thread safe, which I know for a fact too. However, looking at Microsoft's documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0), their WhenAll example takes a Task list, and seem to work as expected. Is it because they are synchronously waiting for the WhenAll result (i.e. WhenAll(tasks).Wait())? I'm asking that because using a list of tasks, in my case, resulted in having only the first task of the list ran to completion. All others seem to hang somehow...

Comment: @Charlesd'Avernas that code isn't modifying the list. `await Task.WhenAll()` runs **a**synchronously *after* the list is filled with tasks

Comment: That `t.Wait()` though is a very, very, *very*, VERY bad example.  It's only used because they couldn't use `await`, because the `Main` method is `void` instead of `async Task`

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Yup, I know, I find unbelievable that they could place such a bad example on their official doc, whereas they advertize everywhere for full async, which is btw perfectly doable in an app's entry point (static async Task Main())... At worst, they should have use the .GetAwaiter().GetResult() methodology which, even if really bad, is way better than calling Wait().

Answer (score 0):

Your task looks like this:

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    var promotionStatus = GetPromotionStatus(promotion).Result;
    var newPromotion = new Promotion
    {
        Id = promotion.Id,
        Name = promotion.Name,
        Code = promotion.Code,
        StatusId = promotionStatus
    };

    outputPromotions.Add(newPromotion);
});
```

outputPromotions is just List. It is not multi-thread safe. So you have race condition while you're trying to add new items into outputPromotions

A suggestion would be to add all those promotions into the list **AFTER** all your tasks have completed. Normally that will not be the bottleneck for your performance.

Comment: Also, why is .Result used? This answer would benefit from showing a better approach.